# Populating JList from inside actionlistener with arraylist

Tags: java, swing, arraylist, jlist

I'm trying to populate a `JList` from an`Arraylist<Member>` from inside an `ActionListener` method.

```
public class guiDemo extends JFrame implements ListSelectionListener {
...
private JList list = new JList();
private JScrollPane sp = new JScrollPane();
...

ActionListener list10 = new ActionListener() {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        win5.setVisible(true);
        p1.setVisible(false);
        String familyName = null;
        int id = 0;
        try {
        familyName = (txt4.getText());
        id = Integer.parseInt(txt3.getText());
        } catch (NumberFormatException ne) {
            System.out.println("error");
            id = 0;
        }
        try{
        ArrayList<Member> result = getMembersForList(id, familyName);
        list = new JList(result.toArray());
        sp = new JScrollPane(list);
        } catch (SQLException se) {
            txt.setText("SQLException!");
        }
        catch ( ClassNotFoundException ce) {
            txt.setText("ClassNotFoundException!");     
        }
    }
};
```

result is the `ArrayList<Member>` that I'm trying to populate the `JList` with, as to create an interface where a user can choose between the objects in the `ArrayList`.

Furthermore:

```
            ...
            b14.addActionListener(list10);
            ...
    win5.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(400, 400));
    win5.setLayout(new GridLayout(10,1));
    win5.setMinimumSize(new Dimension(400, 400));
    win5.add(b13);win5.add(l9);win5.add(txt3);win5.add(l10);
    win5.add(txt4);win5.add(b14);win5.add(l11);
            win5.add(sp);
    list.setVisibleRowCount(15);
    list.setSelectionMode(ListSelectionModel.SINGLE_SELECTION);
    list.addListSelectionListener(this);
            ...
```

As you can see the `JList` is to be located below two `textfields(txtX)`,`labels(lX)` and `buttons (bX)`.

```
            public void valueChanged(ListSelectionEvent e){
        }
```

I believe the problem stems from the fact that I declare the `JList` and `JScrollPane` outside the `actionlistener` and then cannot populate the `JList`. The `valueChanged` method is not completely done (I'd have to solve this problem first) but I don't believe this problem stems from the fact that it is empty.

Populating the `JList` from outside the `ActionListener` will not work since the `ArrayList` has yet to be filled. The idea is that you search for either an id or a familyName or both and get a number of choices based on matches from an SQLite db. The contents of the result `ArrayList` are objects based on the matches from the DB.

I believe this is probably some real rookie mistake, but I would appreciate any help I can get.

The message I get:
[image]

Comment: What are you using to compile the program?  It should not make any difference

Comment: Yep, I just tested this, the `-Xlint` flag is providing warnings about a lack of generics. This means that the compiler can not guarantee that the data the `JList` is expecting is actually the data you are providing.  That is, the way you have it set up, `JList` is expecting elements of type `Object`, but you are providing `Memeber`.  This is not an issue, so long as you've ensured that your renderers can actually handle this.  It's just the compiler telling you, that it has no way to be sure that this is correct behaviour or not...

Comment: Okay. Now that I tried(and tested it despite the warnings) my table is still empty. Any idea why this could be?

The function works(I can print out a correct result at the same place where my Arraylist is trying to populate the JTable), its just that the JTable is not getting any information.

Comment: It's hard to tell, but you've never added the `JScrollPane` to anything...

Comment: The JScrollPane was added, it was for some reason not added to the code in the post. Apologies. I changed it, and looked for other inconsistencies, found none.

I have a feeling its not being filled from inside the ActionListener list10 and that it instead is using the null table I declared in the top of the class. Am I wrong? If not, how do I fix that?

Comment: But WHEN was it added, remember, you've created a brand new instance in the `actionPerformed` method, so if you previously added an instance of it, they have no relevance to each other.  Instead of creating new instances (if you already have an instance), use these instances you already have and have already been added to the screen...

Comment: Oh thank you! That must be it. Could you help me with a code snippet that would fill the table without writing list = new JList(...?

Now I get the error:
guiDemo.java:236: error: incompatible types
                JList<Object[]> list = (result.toArray());
 required: JList<Object[]>
 found:    Object[]

And a following error by ScrollPane that is most likely because of the previous error.

Comment: I see that I mentioned a JTable above, which has to relevance. Apologies. I meant a JList.

Comment: I added an answer which I "hope" helps...

Answer (score 2):

First, the `-Xlint` flag is providing warnings about a lack of generics.

This means that the compiler can not guarantee that the data the `JList` is expecting is actually the data you are providing. That is, the way you have it set up, `JList` is expecting elements of type Object, but you are providing `Memeber`.

This is not an issue, so long as you've ensured that your renderers can actually handle this. It's just the compiler telling you, that it has no way to be sure that this is correct behaviour or not...This might cause issues at run time.

It is preferred where possible, tp provide support for generics, but it's not always possible.

```
private JList<Member> list ...;

//...

ArrayList<Member> result = getMembersForList(id, familyName);
list = new JList(result.toArray(new Member[result.size()]));
```

This will allow you to trap possible errors at compile time rather than hitting an error at run time...

Second, let me make some guesses...

You create an instance of `JList` and `JScrollPane`...

```
private JList list = new JList();
private JScrollPane sp = new JScrollPane();
```

You then add these to the UI...

```
sp.setViewportView(list);
add(sp); // for example...
```

Then in your `actionPerformed` method, you create new instances of these objects...

```
list = new JList(result.toArray());
sp = new JScrollPane(list);
```

But never add them to the UI and some how magically expect that they will know how to link to the previous instances and update the UI...?

That's not how it works.  The instances you have created in the `actionPerformed` method have no relationship to the objects you created previously.  Instead, you should be changing the `JList`'s model, for example...

```
ActionListener list10 = new ActionListener() {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        //...
        try{
            //ArrayList<Member> result = getMembersForList(id, familyName);
            //list = new JList(result.toArray());
            //sp = new JScrollPane(list);
            DefaultListModel model = new DefaultListModel();
            for (Member member : getMembersForList(id, familyName)) {
                model.addElement(member);
            }
            list.setModel(model);
        //...
    }
};
```

Comment: Just one question:

Now I got a list with the type Object.

I still want to be able to use every different attribute of the Arraylist<Member> objects  that I made before. Is there a way that I can convert this to a ArrayList<Member> and have the same attributes I got from the ArrayList I got from the getMembersForList method?

Comment: If I understand your question correctly, take a look at [How to Use Lists](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/list.html) and pay close attention to [Writing a Custom Cell Renderer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/list.html#renderer). This will allow you to define the attributes of the object that are displayed in the `JList`

Answer (score 1):

I think this is just because JList is a generic type and you try to use it as raw type.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JList.html

Note that these are just warnings, not errors.
If you say `JList<Member>`, these warnings will probably go away.

Comment: So the fact that I have the JList and ScrollPane inside the actionlistener after declaring it as "private" in the start of the class is no problem?

Heading to your link now to bash some knowledge into this thick head of mine.

Comment: Maybe you need to read up a bit about generic types vs raw types. See my 1st link. Note this `Class JList<E>` - this `<E>` there indicates it's a generic type.

Comment: Adding <Member> on JList both when declared and in the ActionListener did not work.

I got the error "No suitable constructor found for JList(ArrayList(<Member>))

Comment: I think you want `ArrayList<Member>()`, but `JList` will only take an array of `Member`

Comment: I thought that was what the result.toArray() method fixed?

Comment: Yes, but 1- `JList` does not have a constructor that takes a `Collection` or `List` 2- You don't declare a generic list like `ArrayList(<?>)`...it's `ArrayList<?>()` where `?` is the type you want...